# Put 3 divs inside one div centralized

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<div class="featured-video">
    <div class="video-title">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Subtitle</p>
        <p>Author</p>
    </div>
    <div class="video">
        <object width="420" height="315" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sewZ2a-LBcQ?feature=player_embedded">
        </object>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-area">
        <img src="http://localhost/artver/images/artver_logo_2010.jpg"/ alt="artver.com" width="298" height="53">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the 3 divs to stay in same line, and centered. I tried the css code below to do the work but I can't achieve what I want.

```
.featured-video .video-title {
    width: 25%;
    margin: auto;
}

.featured-video .video-title, .video {
    display: inline-block;
}

.featured-video .logo-area {
    display: inline;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I'm new to css3. I tried some variations of the css code but nothing.

Comment: `div.featured-video' is not closed properly. It may just be your example

Comment: You give to parent block and 2/3 child blocks `display-inline` and the last has simple `inline`. Suspicious

Comment: Center how? Horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Code html corrected @geedubb.

Comment: Thanks. As a side note I'd recommend using the iframe embed technique for your youtube vid. That way you get served HTML5 video or Flash depending on the device / browser https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds

Comment: @lolbas, the last inline was due inline-block made the image overlap object video. I want to center both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @Caco is it what u want? [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wnmco2bx/)

Comment: Yes, @lolbas, the jsfiddle example is great. I had only to change `width:300px` in `featured-video` class to `width:100%` for the `display: table` to occupy all screen. The only thing missing is horizontal align of the 3 divs.

Comment: @Caco You want to center titles horizontaly ?

Comment: Yes @aloisdg but the image in third column overlap youtube video. See my comment below your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @lolbas, your example worked for me, changing `width:300px` to `width:100` in `featured-video` class and adding `text-align:center` in `video-title`, `video` and `logo-area` classes. If you can put your comment in answar. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to center vertically and split the place in three, try this :

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnmco2bx/1/)

**html**

```
<!-- the comment is a hack to remove unwanted whitespace -->
<div class="featured-video">
    <div class="video-title">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Subtitle</p>
        <p>Author</p>
    </div><!--
     --><div class="video"></div><!--
    --><div class="logo-area"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
// cleaner
* {
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
}

// take all the place
.featured-video {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.video-title,
.video,
.logo-area {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; // everything in a line
    width: 33%; // 100 / 3
    vertical-align: middle; // center vertically
}

.video-title {
    background : green;
}

.video {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.logo-area {
    height : 200px;
    background: blue;
    width: 34%; // 100 /3
}
```

[more info about the html hack](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Thanks @aloisdg. Only that my image in third column continues to overlap the youtube video. But that is because the video dimensions fill more than 33% of the screen. With `display: table` and `display: table-cell` that overlapping disappears.

Comment: you should make some effort **your fiddle is found in lolbas comment**

Comment: @sanojlawrence yes I opened it. I just forgot to update the link. Thank you for the notification.